# How to handle promotional ads or cookies in Selenium webdriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium

I was trying to handle alerts in Selenium web-driver using java. But while logging into the chrome web page, there appears a promotional ad or current affair add on top of page which overrides the alert pop-up..I'm not able to see that ad always..So i need to find a way to check if there is any promotional ad's or something like that and if yes, i need to close it..I just shared example of the Ad above..Please let me know if it is considered as ad or cookie and how to handle it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case there is a close link with the id "close". You can use the following code to close that ad:

```
    WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"close\"]"));
    element1.click();
```

But there is no generic way to do this. There are countless ways to place promotional ads or something similar in the way of your popup. But if it is a real alert, it should be reachable by

```
    driver.switchTo().alert()
```